# Colour Filling using VBA, Conditional on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to colour fill a range of cells (C2:C7) in Excel based on the the text selected in a cell (there will be a drop-down menu, two of the values being "SD" and "CS"). Here is my code so far:

Sub ChangeColor()
    Dim rCell As Range

```
With Sheet1
For Each rCell In .Range("C2:C7")

If rCell.Value <= SD Then
rCell.Interior.Color = vbRed
ElseIf rCell.Value <= CS Then
rCell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
Else: rCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
End If
End With

End Sub
```

I'm told there is a compile error: End With without With

I'm just getting started in VBA so can somebody please tell me what I've done wrong?

Comment: `Conditional formatting` is also a way to do this :D as long as you manage it properly it will not make the sheet bulky..

Comment: I can do it using conditional formatiing, however there are 5 names on the drop down list and I also want to do other things like highlight certain rows with a specific colour if a drop down name is selected. Hence I tried VBA.. any suggestions?

Comment: If you're using Excel 2007 or higher, you can do this with Conditional formatting.

Comment: Cheers, will have a play!

Answer (score 5):

To fix your code, you need to insert a `Next`statement. before the  `End With` line. Also, it is good practice to use indentation to visually see the different code blocks. In your case, it would look like this:

```
Sub YourSub
    With Sheet1
        For Each rCell In .Range("C2:C7")
            If rCell.Value <= SD Then
                rCell.Interior.Color = vbRed
            ElseIf rCell.Value <= CS Then
                rCell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
            Else
                rCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End If
        Next rCell
    End With
End Sub
```

Also, consider to use Conditional Formatting instead of VBA here - it will do the same, but much easier!

Comment: [Smart Indenter](http://www.oaltd.co.uk/Indenter/Default.htm) is a useful addin (works with 2007 & 2010 too, verified by personal use) that will help you indent code to help make it more readable

Comment: Agree - quite a useful tool! Though I'd suggest to make it good habit to manually indent correctly during coding (so that errors can be seen during coding) - and only use Smart Indenter to fix ugly code/verify own code...

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if it is working but you can try this, because when you type in script  "For commands" then you need to type next. And "For" is more used to create loops:

```
Sub ChangeColor()
    Dim rCell As Range
    With Sheet1
    For Each rCell In .Range("C2:C7")
        If rCell.Value <= SD Then
            rCell.Interior.Color = vbRed
        ElseIf rCell.Value <= CS Then
            rCell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
        Else rCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    Next
    End With
End Sub
```